# preallocated memory in java

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I heard that on real time system it is preferred to be used pre-allocated memory to avoid garbage as much as possible. But what exactly does it mean? As I know whenever we call new operator we use heap memory on runtime. So how achieve to use pre-allocated memory?

Answer (score 1):

"Pre-allocated memory" means that a program should allocate all the required memory blocks once after startup (using the `new` operator, as usual), rather than allocate memory multiple times during execution and leave memory which is no longer needed for the garbage collector to free.

Answer (score 0):

Pre-allocated memory means a memory which is allocate at the time of loading a program, In `java` using `static` keyword we can achieve.

For more info refer [this](http://www.journaldev.com/4098/java-heap-space-vs-stack-memory)